# Is there something wrong with my System.Xml.Linq library?

Tags: .net, linq, dll

I'm trying to learn some Linq to XML stuff, and I came across the XPathSelectElement function in XElement.  This function seems to do just what I need, but for some reason, I can't use it!  Check out my code:

```
        XElement rootElement = XElement.Load(dataFile);
        XElement parentElement = rootElement.XPathSelectElement(xPath);
```

I have included references to System.Xml.Linq everywhere that is needed.  All the other stuff in that library that I have tried appears to be working, but XPathSelectElement doesn't even appear in the Intellisense in visual studio.

When building the above code, I get the following error:

> Error 1   'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'XPathSelectElement' and no extension
>   method 'XPathSelectElement' accepting
>   a first argument of type
>   'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' could be
>   found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\PageHelpControl\PageHelp.cs  155 50  HelpControl

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The methods you are trying to use are extension menthods. You need to include System.Xml.XPath namespace.

Answer (score 15):

Just to tie the two answers together...

[`XPathSelectElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.extensions.xpathselectelement.aspx) is an extension method. To use it *as* an extension method (i.e. as if it were an instance method on [`XNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.aspx)) you need to have a `using` directive in your source code for the relevant namespace:

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
```

(That's where the [`Extensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.extensions.aspx) class which contains the extension method lives.)

This works in the same way that you need `using System.Linq;` in your code before you can use `Select`, `Where` etc on `IEnumerable<T>`.